# Can you insert an external webpage as a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a View inside my webpage, but `Html.ActionLink` only works with a `Controller`, which I'm not trying to retrieve a `View`.

I tried using `Html.ActionLink` and using the `Controller` to `Redirect` to the URL, but it redirects the page instead of changing the inner `View`.

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("MyExtPage", "MyExtPage", "Home")</li>

 public ActionResult MyExtPage() {
      return Redirect("http://my.url/");
 }
```

With a created View, I can just return the View, but what if I want to return a webpage that is served up externally? I really don't want to have to use `frames` if I don't have to.

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
      ViewBag.Title = "Home";
      return View();
 }
```

The above works because I have an `Index.cshtml` file, but what if I want to insert `http://google.com` as a View, for example?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do... what's wrong with `<a href="http://google.com">`, i.e. why does it need to be a view?

Answer (score 1):

> The above works because I have an Index.cshtml file, but what if I
>   want to insert http://google.com as a View, for example?

You could download the contents of this remote location (using an HTTP client such as the WebClient class for example) and then return it as Content result. For example:

For example you could write a custom view result that will do the job:

```
public class RemoteViewResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly Uri uri;
    public RemoteViewResult(Uri uri)
    {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(this.uri))
            {
                var response = context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response; 
                stream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
                response.ContentType = client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new RemoteViewResult(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do it like that. The view has to be a proper view in your website.  If you really didn't want to use frames to display the external page content you could try using a WebRequest to pull back the Html into a model/ViewBag and then render that to your local view.

This has a number of potential issues tho, you'd need to render the raw html to the page which could leave you open to XSS attacks from the external site. Also you could run into timeouts if the external page didn't respond in a timely manner and you lose any session control from the external site, it would see every request as coming from the same end user.

Answer (score 0):

> but what if I want to insert http://google.com [in] a View, for example?

You can either display it using an `<iframe />` or by pulling in the HTML serverside using a WebClient and writing that to your view. Neither is encouraged.